# Python - Showing a web browser/iframe right into the app

Tags: python, iframe, browser, kivy

I have a script which if helpful to people answering questions, is using kivy.
I want to have it show a iframe kind of thing right into it when run, instead of opening
the browser. For example something like this:

```
def browser():
    url = "google.com"
    iframe(url)
browser()
```

Obviously this wouldnt work as python is not html. Keep in mind, I am not trying to run
this script on the web, but on the kivy launcher. As intended, it should not open
the webbrowser but instead show the page in a box built right into the script.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an actual running example which works right inside the "Kivy Launcher" app:

```
import kivy                                                                                     
from kivy.app import App                                                                        
from kivy.lang import Builder                                                                   
from kivy.utils import platform                                                                 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget                                                              
from kivy.clock import Clock                                                                    
from jnius import autoclass                                                                     
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread                                                   

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')                                                   
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')                                       
activity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity                              

class Wv(Widget):                                                                               
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                               
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)                                                      
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)                                             

    @run_on_ui_thread                                                                           
    def create_webview(self, *args):                                                            
        webview = WebView(activity)                                                             
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)                                        
        wvc = WebViewClient();                                                                  
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);                                                          
        activity.setContentView(webview)                                                        
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com')

class ServiceApp(App):                                                                          
    def build(self):                                                                            
        return Wv()                                                                             

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
    ServiceApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do this on an android device? There's currently not a build in way to do this, but I'm pretty sure it's possible to load a native android webview via pyjnius. I'm not sure the current state, but for example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/9sH0y3KxCuU) is an example of how to do it. I've pasted some of the code below, but I recommend asking on the kivy mailing list or irc if you have any questions, as this kind of thing is under discussion and development.

```
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
LayoutParams = autoclass('android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams')
activity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_webview()

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def create_webview(self):
        webview = WebView(activity)
        activity.addContentView(webview, LayoutParams(-1, -1))
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
        #having some trouble with this one: webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        html = "<html><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>\
            <script type='text/javascript'\
            src='http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=ID_HERE'>\
            </script></body></html>"    

        activity.setContentView(webview)
        webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8")
        layout = LinearLayout(activity)
        layout.addView(activity.mView)
        activity.setContentView(layout)
```

Comment: I tried doing:

class MyApp(App) :
    def build(self) :
        return Wv()

but, the app just crashes when trying to create the webview widget.

Should native android widgets be nested in another widget or something in order to run?

Comment: Android widgets wouldn't be part of kivy's normal widget tree, they can only be displayed on top of or behind the entire kivy window

Comment: I actually didn't read my answer you were commenting on here, your code (returning `Wv()`) should actually work, since Wv is a kivy widget that only instantiates the android webview. That makes my answer above misleading, sorry! I suggest posting a new question (or probably even better, a kivy mailing list post) with your code and details of the error.