# Python Kivy - App that open url in a native web browser

Tags: android, python, browser, kivy, native

I try to make a simple app that open a web page inside Kivy after clicking a button placed on a "Screen One".

I used this topic ([Python - Showing a web browser/iframe right into the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263752/python-showing-a-web-browser-iframe-right-into-the-app)) as reference but I didn't understand how to use the code provided by Michael...

So I tried this... and when I launch the apk (build with Buildozer) it didn't work :')

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# MICHAEL'S CODE
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from jnius import autoclass
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')
activity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def create_webview(self, *args):
        webview = WebView(activity)
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
        wvc = WebViewClient();
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);
        activity.setContentView(webview)
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com/')
# END OF MICHAEL'S CODE

Builder.load_string('''

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "SCREEN 1"
        Button:
            text: "GO GO GO TO GOOGLE !"
            on_press: root.open_browser()

<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "SCREEN 2"
        Button:
            text: "GO GO GO TO SCREEN 1"
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = "screen_one"

''')

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def open_browser(self):
        return Wv()

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

screen_manager = ScreenManager()

screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))


class BrowserApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

app = BrowserApp()
app.run()
```

The app don't crash but just close when I start it.

What I'm doing wrong ? I'm sure that I don't use it the right way...

Log from `adb logcat`:

> 06-13 12:54:47.559  7429  7510 I python  :  ImportError: No module named android
>
> 06-13 12:54:47.579  7429  7510 I python  : Python for android ended.

Comment: "I didn't understand how to use the code" That's why copy&paste is bad way for actually implementing anything unless you know what such a code does. You should look at some **basic** [examples](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/) first :) "...it didn't work :') What I'm doing wrong ?" That's what [`adb logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) is for. No one will compile and run it on own device which is why you need to provide the log too. Also, the java class actually has [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Yeah I know that copy&paste is bad... So I start studying Michael's code with the link that you provided. On an other hand I made an adb logcat and got this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_6xoiJkXbGWjRZbDZkR0ZiTjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the log you posted in the comments I extracted the two important lines:

```
06-13 12:54:47.559 7429 7510 I python : ImportError: No module named android
06-13 12:54:47.579 7429 7510 I python : Python for android ended.
```

This basically means that the copied code:

```
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
```

won't work because it doesn't detect the `android` module. The module has a separate [recipe](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/__init__.py), therefore you will need to add it to the requirements, so that it compiles the Cython code and adds it to your app, otherwise the import will always fail.

Basically you always want to search for 3-4 keywords when looking into such a messy logcat → "python", "Traceback", "Python for android", "kivy". There's a filter in [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) for that if you use it:

```
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
```

Comment: Oh that's how you read a log... I added the `android module` in the requirement and TADA: I've got a crash message !  Here is a new log:     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B68O3RHHvPQDcW5nZ1FYdDFiMDQ/view?usp=sharing   Is there a link with the `06-14 09:52:45.131  5040  5160 I python  : crystax_python does not exist` ?

Comment: You need to use `org.kivy.android.PythonActivity` instead of `org.renpy.android.PythonActivity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !! Now I just need to implement a back button to return/navigate to the last web page/Menu and it will be usable ! Thanks again !

Comment: @Dahaarl you can thank me with accepting the answer :)